# Correctly using an accessor in tbb

Tags: c++, concurrency, tbb

I have a list of items to insert into tbb's concurrent hash map. What's the correct way of using an accessor, way 1 or 2?

```
// way 1
for (a list of (keys,values))
{
    MAP::accessor a;

    myHashTable.insert(a, key);
    (a->second).push_back(value);

    a.realease();
}

// way 2

MAP::accessor a;

for (a list of (keys,values))
{ 
    myHashTable.insert(a, key);
    (a->second).push_back(value);

    a.realease();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically either, since you explicitly call to `accessor::release()`. But generally, from the code quality point of view, I'd limit the scope of the locking to minimal necessary region since the code could be extended further in unexpected way or/and an exception-safety could be an issue.

The third way without explicit release is:

```
// way 3
for (a list of (keys,values))
{
    MAP::accessor a;

    myHashTable.insert(a, key);
    (a->second).push_back(value);
}
```

P.S. Try to avoid using of accessor in the serial code when possible, e.g. use insert(value_type) form. It will help to reduce the overheads of thread-safety

Comment: If I adopt way 3, wouldn't tbb hold a lock on the object until I explicitly release it or the thread dies?

Comment: It follows [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)  thus it will be released in the destructor at the end of scope for 'a' object.